# Multiplying list of matrices with vector of scalars

Tags: matrix, vector

there are many similar threads on this forum, but none of them fixes my problem. I am trying to multiply List of Pauli Matrices with a vector of symbols (which are scalars).

```
PauliMatrices[Range[3]].{W1, W2, W3}
```

and I would like to get something like

```
{{W3, W1 - I W2},{W1 + I W2, -W3}}.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this, is to use `Inner` with a level specification. In this case, you want the inner product to work only on the first level:

```
Inner[Times, PauliMatrix[Range[3]], {W1, W2, W3}, Plus, 1]
```

> > {{W3, W1 - I W2}, {W1 + I W2, -W3}}

*Edit*
Alternatively, you can exchange the order of the `Dot` product:

```
{W1, W2, W3}.PauliMatrix[Range[3]]
```

> > {{W3, W1 - I W2}, {W1 + I W2, -W3}}

The reason this works, is because `Dot` contracts the last index of the first argument with the first index of the last argument. Since `Dimensions[PauliMatrix[Range[3]]]` equals `{3, 2, 2}`, it should be the second argument of `Dot` if you want to contract it with a length-3 vector.